# JS free Button linked with a "popup"/overlay

Tags: button, hyperlink, popup, overlay

I try to open a 'popup'/overlay with a `javascript button`. Unfortunately my button does not to open it.

Where I am making mistake? Is there a better way to do it?

It should be `javascript` free.

…………………………………………………………………………………………………………………

```css
/* popup */


.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
.overlay:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.popup {
  margin: 70px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}

.popup h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #333;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.popup .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2%;
  right: 4%;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}
.popup .close:hover {
  color: orange;
}
.popup .content {
  max-height: 30%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<button href="#popup4">btn1</button> 
<div id="popup4" class="overlay">
    <div class="popup"><h2>Here i am</h2>
     <a class="close" href="#">×</a>
    <div class="content">
     Thank to pop me out of that button, but now i'm done so you can close this window.
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button alone doesn't do anything, it has to submit via a form.

```
<form method="get" action="#popup4">
    <button>btn1</button>
</form>
```